# Shapely Polygon intersect in order Python

Tags: python, intersection, shapely

I have 2 list of Polygon as below:

```
list1 = [p1, p2, p3]
list2 = [pa, pb, pc]
```

I want to check if p1 overlaps pa, p2 overlaps pb, and p3 overlaps pc. I used `shapely.intersects` to check whether they overlap with each other. But I don't know how to choose exactly p1 vs pa, p2 vs pb, p3 vs pc. How can I do that?

Comment: can you show what do you mean by polygon intersection and what did you try ?

Comment: I mean I want to check if 1 polygon in list 1 is overlapped by a corresponded polygon in list 2. I tried 
`for i, j in zip(list1, list2):
    if( i.intersects(j) == True):
        print("Something")
    else:
        print("Something")`

Comment: However, is there any other way to check that one polygon is overlapped a lot by another, likes 1 polygon stay above another polygon? Since by using `shapely.intersection`, it always True even if there's a small overlapping part, likes some points

Answer (score 1):

Use `zip` for that:

```
for i, j in zip(list1, list2):
    print(i, j)
```

in each iteration `i,j` will be the same index of two different lists.